# Table function on elements of a list

Tags: r

I have a list that looks like this:

> list[[1]]
>
> ```
>  GN  SN1  SN2      
>   a   0    0      
>   b   1    1     
>   c   0    0    
>   e   2    2     
>   f   0    1    
>   d   0    0
> ```
>
> list[[2]]
>
> ```
>  GN  SN1  SN2      
>   e   0    1      
>   f   2    0     
>   g   1    1    
>   h   2    0     
>   i   1    0    
>   l   3    0
> ```

I would like to apply the "table" function to each element of the list (so for each list[[1]], list[[2]],...) first by columns and then by rows using for example such a structure: apply(list, 1, table) (lapply for lists) or apply(list, 2, table) and in the same manner to sum by row and after by columns.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried wrongly lapply(list, table)..

Comment: And why was it wrong? We're not mind readers.

Comment: Probably I have to write a specific functon but I'm not able at the moment since I'm a beginner in R..

Comment: Ok, the error is the following: "Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
"

Comment: I am really curious , why do you want to use `table`? We apply `table` to compute frequency not to get the sum. Can you add the expected output at least?

Comment: Hi agstudy. Yes, you're right. As a matter of fact they are two computations for two independent purposes. I edit the post adding the desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be something like this...

```
lapply(List, apply, 1, table) # table by row
lapply(List, apply, 2, table) # table by cols
```

The output isn't nice.

A nicer output could be:

```
list1 <- lapply(List, apply, 1, table) # table by row
list2 <- lapply(List, apply, 2, table) # table by cols

> # for list1
> lapply(list1, unlist) # output is a list
[[1]]
0 a 1 b 0 c 2 e 0 1 f 0 d 
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 

[[2]]
0 1 e 0 2 f 1 g 0 2 h 0 1 i 0 3 l 
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 


> # for list2
> library(abind)
> # using abind function from abind package
> abind(lapply(list2, unlist), along=0)  # output is an array
     GN.e GN.f GN.g GN.h GN.i GN.l SN1.0 SN1.1 SN1.2 SN1.3 SN2.0 SN2.1
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1     4     1     1     3     2     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     2     2     1     4     2

> # R base solution
> do.call(rbind, lapply(list2, unlist)) # output is an array
     GN.a GN.b GN.c GN.d GN.e GN.f SN1.0 SN1.1 SN1.2 SN2.0 SN2.1 SN2.2
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1     4     1     1     3     2     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     2     2     1     4     2
```

Comment: semantically it is correct , but the output is really ugly!

Comment: I agree with you @agstudy, so I did some tricks for the output to be a bit nicer than they were before :D it's still ugly I think.

Comment: Hi guys! no problem for the ugly output...it runs and for me this is the only important thing. Thank you so much Jiber for your precious help!

Comment: @Bfu38 Glad to be useful.

Comment: @Jilber  +1 for the abind!